# Reduce SNS alerts ofr failed ECS tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, devops, amazon-ecs, amazon-sns

I have created ECS tasks but due to somereason its failing and for the alert service I have used SNS integerated with my slack channel. When a container fails to start ...it gives alert and it has the property that it keeps on restarting everytime until it is stopped manually, and everytime it restarts ..it gives alerts ...I want t reduce these alerts ,,is there someway I can do that. like putting code in the eventrule or adding conditional loops in the same. please help...below are the codes used for two cases:

Answer (score 2):

The task and container are being replaced, not restarted. I don't think there's any way to reduce the number of alerts that will be sent out, since it's a new task each time. At least not with EventBridge/SNS directly.

You could look at creating a CloudWatch Alert that monitors the number of running tasks, and have it send an alert to your SNS topic when the count is 0 (or below some threshold). A CloudWatch Alert has settings like evaluation period that you can adjust to prevent too many alerts from occurring, and it also would only send an alert when the count changed, not on every ECS task deployment attempt.

Comment: there is an option for deployement secutiy breaker...can we chose enable with no roll back option and it will be stopped automatically if giving me only one alert. can you guide me a little on this

Comment: Read up on the deployment circuit beaker: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/announcing-amazon-ecs-deployment-circuit-breaker/ It looks like it will try at least 10 times before stopping the deployment. Enable the circuit breaker if that is the actual deployment behavior you want, don't enable it just to cut down on notifications.

Comment: The way I tackled these issues was to write the ecs service events out to cloudwatch - https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwet.html. There are specific terms used when a container can't start properly, fails a health check etc - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/stopped-task-error-codes.html. Using metric filter alarms I can count how many times the error appears and then trigger an alarm when it meets a threshold that seems appropriate.